# Map json values to array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am using datatables. I have a response that I need to show in datatable. Now, for the testing, I have taken a json and I am not able to extract values from it?

I checked there is `jquery.map` but I am not getting how to use it.

This is my json -

```
var json =  [{"_attr":{"col_Decision":{"_value":"Count"},"col1":{"_value":"2,698"},"col2":{"_value":"1,724"},"col3":{"_value":"4,422"},"col4":{"_value":"1,457"},"col5":{"_value":"1,047"},"col6":{"_value":"2,504"},"col7":{"_value":"1,241"},"col8":{"_value":677},"col9":{"_value":"1,918"}},"_text":[null]},{"_attr":{"col_Decision":{"_value":"Avg Days"},"col1":{"_value":4},"col2":{"_value":2.2},"col3":{"_value":3.3},"col4":{"_value":4},"col5":{"_value":1.9},"col6":{"_value":3.1},"col7":{"_value":4},"col8":{"_value":2.8},"col9":{"_value":3.5}},"_text":[null]},{"_attr":{"col_Decision":{"_value":"Goal Met %"},"col1":{"_value":84.2},"col2":{"_value":90.8},"col3":{"_value":86.8},"col4":{"_value":79.9},"col5":{"_value":91.1},"col6":{"_value":84.6},"col7":{"_value":89.4},"col8":{"_value":90.4},"col9":{"_value":89.7}},"_text":[null]}]
```

Now I need the values of col_Decision, col1, col2, col3,...col9. There are 3 rows. So it will be 3 times in the response.

Its probably very easy but I am not getting it.

Failing code -

```
var itemvalue = arrayObj.data[0].itemlist[0].item;
                        const data = JSON.stringify(itemvalue);
                       // var myJsonString = JSON.stringify(itemvalue);
                        //console.log(myJsonString);
                        console.log(data);
                        //loadDataTable(data);

                            const rows = data.map( 
                            ({_attr}) => Object.keys(_attr).map ( key => _attr[key]._value )
                            ); 

                        console.log(rows);
```

Comment: Is this is what you want `var result = json.map(function(obj) {
  return obj._attr;
});`

Comment: no I want value for each column

Comment: Please read the usage description of the `json` tag. This is not about JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using JS, You might need to iterate each of the object's properties inside.
In iterating, you might need this:

```
var aAssignColumnData = [];
for (var iIndex in json) {
    // We'll assign this variable to the [_attr] inside [json] object
    aAssignColumnData.push(json[iIndex]._attr);
}

// Now, [aAssignColumnData] has the object values containing the [_attr] object values.
for (var iColumnIndex in aAssignColumnData) {
    if (aAssignColumnData.hasOwnProperty(iColumnIndex) === true) {

       // e.g _attr[0] / _attr[1] / _attr[2]
       var oColumnNames = aAssignColumnData[iColumnIndex];

       // Then we'll get the number of properties inside the [json's _attr] values
       var iLength = Object.keys(oColumnNames).length; // e.g 10, since 3 of your [_attr] had 10 objects inside.

       // Then we'll iterate each of them using {for}
       for (var iCtr = 0; iCtr < iLength; iCtr++) {
           if (typeof oColumnNames['col' + iCtr] === 'object') {
               console.log(oColumnNames['col' + iCtr]['_value']);
           } else {
               // This is to retrieve the ['col_Decision'] property
               if (typeof oColumnNames['col_Decision'] === 'object') {
                  console.log(oColumnNames['col_Decision']['_value']);
               }
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's a jsfiddle for further reference: https://jsfiddle.net/8b99z0tL/

Hope this helps for your case.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this? It uses `map` and `es2015` lambas.

```
Array.from(Array(3)).map((a, i) => {
    return Array.from(Array(9)).map((b, j) => {
       return json[i]._attr["col"+(j+1)]._value;
    });
});
```

You could do it also with plain nested loops:

```
var result = [];
for(i=0; i<3; i++){
    var row = []
    for(j=1; j<=9; j++){
        row.push(json[i]._attr["col"+j])._value;
    }
    result.push(row)
}
```

Comment: for this do I need to add any library?

Comment: No, it's vanilla javascript.

Comment: there is one more column "col_Decision" whose value is needed

Answer (score 0):

You can use this ES6 code:

```
data.map( ({_attr}) => Object.keys(_attr).map ( key => _attr[key]._value ) );
```

```js
const data =  [{"_attr":{"col_Decision":{"_value":"Count"},"col1":{"_value":"2,698"},"col2":{"_value":"1,724"},"col3":{"_value":"4,422"},"col4":{"_value":"1,457"},"col5":{"_value":"1,047"},"col6":{"_value":"2,504"},"col7":{"_value":"1,241"},"col8":{"_value":677},"col9":{"_value":"1,918"}},"_text":[null]},{"_attr":{"col_Decision":{"_value":"Avg Days"},"col1":{"_value":4},"col2":{"_value":2.2},"col3":{"_value":3.3},"col4":{"_value":4},"col5":{"_value":1.9},"col6":{"_value":3.1},"col7":{"_value":4},"col8":{"_value":2.8},"col9":{"_value":3.5}},"_text":[null]},{"_attr":{"col_Decision":{"_value":"Goal Met %"},"col1":{"_value":84.2},"col2":{"_value":90.8},"col3":{"_value":86.8},"col4":{"_value":79.9},"col5":{"_value":91.1},"col6":{"_value":84.6},"col7":{"_value":89.4},"col8":{"_value":90.4},"col9":{"_value":89.7}},"_text":[null]}];

const rows = data.map( 
    ({_attr}) => Object.keys(_attr).map ( key => _attr[key]._value )
); 

console.log(rows);
```

NB: Don't call your variable *json*, since it is not: it is a JavaScript object. It would be JSON if it were a string.

Comment: when I using it is saying ReferenceError: data is not defined

Comment: Run the snippet please. Like I wrote, don't call your variable *json*, but something else, like *data*, which is what I did.

Comment: this error is coming... -  data.map is not a function

Comment: Then your code is different from the snippet. Please check what is different. Or, post a snippet yourself (or jsfiddle) that reproduces that error. Does the snippet work for you, when you run it from *within* my answer?

Comment: So, can you provide a fiddle with your failing code?

Comment: Well that `JSON.stringify(...)` makes no sense as it will produce a string. Take it out, and just let `data = itemvalue`, or work directly with `itemvalue`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
var json =  [{"_attr":{"col_Decision":{"_value":"Count"},"col1":{"_value":"2,698"},"col2":{"_value":"1,724"},"col3":{"_value":"4,422"},"col4":{"_value":"1,457"},"col5":{"_value":"1,047"},"col6":{"_value":"2,504"},"col7":{"_value":"1,241"},"col8":{"_value":677},"col9":{"_value":"1,918"}},"_text":[null]},{"_attr":{"col_Decision":{"_value":"Avg Days"},"col1":{"_value":4},"col2":{"_value":2.2},"col3":{"_value":3.3},"col4":{"_value":4},"col5":{"_value":1.9},"col6":{"_value":3.1},"col7":{"_value":4},"col8":{"_value":2.8},"col9":{"_value":3.5}},"_text":[null]},{"_attr":{"col_Decision":{"_value":"Goal Met %"},"col1":{"_value":84.2},"col2":{"_value":90.8},"col3":{"_value":86.8},"col4":{"_value":79.9},"col5":{"_value":91.1},"col6":{"_value":84.6},"col7":{"_value":89.4},"col8":{"_value":90.4},"col9":{"_value":89.7}},"_text":[null]}]

for(var i=0;i<json.length;i++){
    var keyNames,valueObj;
    var attrObj=json[i]._attr;
    for (keyNames in attrObj) {
        valueObj=attrObj[keyNames];
        console.log(keyNames+" : "+valueObj._value);
    }
}
</script>
```

`keyNames` will give you name of the key and `valueObj._value` will give you value of that particular key.